# How to get regular expression that matches these strings

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to make regular expression for a `String` shown blow coming in via TCP/IP socket.

```
$AVSYS,99999999,V1.17,SN0000103,32768*16
```

Each string should start with dollar sign `$`  and capital alpha character between 5 and 6 digits. They end with `*` and 2 digits alphanumeric check-sum. Each fields is separated by comma `,` and can be any string.

I created a regular expression for it.

```
^\$[A-Z]{5,6}(\,.*)(\,.*)(\,.*)(\,.*)(\,.*)\*[\d\w]{2}$
```

I expected that it would match but it did not. I am not still familiar with regular expression even though I have read through Java doc. Please help for me to get correct regular expression.

## Edited

I tried these two after I fixed my regular expression according to replies.

```
^\$[A-Z]{5,6}(\,.*)(\,.*)(\,.*)(\,.*)(\,.*)\*[\d\w]{2}$
^\$[A-Z]{5,6}(\,.*?)(\,.*?)(\,.*?)(\,.*?)\*[\d\w]{2}$
```

But I got the more result than I expected.

```
$AVSYS,99999999,V1.17,SN0000103,32768*16
$AVRMC,80000551,144811,A,4351.3789,N,07923.4712,W,0.00,153.45,091107,A,,161,1*64
$AVRMC,80000551,144811,A,4351.3789,N,07923.4712,W,0.00,153.45,091107,A,,161,1,0,0*64
$EAVSYS,99999999,12345678901234567890,9057621228,,,*0B
```

Above sentences all match with the regexp.But I want to get just 1).
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have more `,` than the string has. http://www.regex101.com/r/qF8hS9 You need `Matcher` class to extract tokens, or use split with appropriate regex.

Comment: Thanks for the point. Then how can I match the string exactly? I tried with fixed regexp but I got different result than I expected. Please see my question again(edited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match any number of comma-separated groups, you can use this expression:

```
^\$[A-Z]{5,6}(,[^,*]*)*\*[\da-zA-Z]{2}$
```

The data portion is matched by this expression:

```
(,[^,*]*)*
```

It matches zero or more groups of characters that start in comma, and followed by any number of characters other than a comma or an asterisk. Once a comma or an asterisk is reached, the expression engine checks if it's a new value or the check sum at the end.

If the check sum does not allow lowercase letters, replace `a-zA-Z` with `A-Z`.

Comment: Note that `\w` includes the underscore character. Change `\w` to `a-zA-Z` to be strict

Answer (score 1):

Your regex has an extra sub-group.  This should work:

```
^\$[A-Z]{5,6}(\,.*)(\,.*)(\,.*)(\,.*)\*[\d\w]{2}$
```

On a side note, this should also work, but with a better efficiency as it would eliminate a lot of back-tracking; the '?' added makes the regex match in a non-greedy fashion.

```
^\$[A-Z]{5,6}(\,.*?)(\,.*?)(\,.*?)(\,.*?)\*[\d\w]{2}$
```

As to your new edits, you could use the following:

```
^\$[A-Z]{5,6}(\,[^\,]+?)(\,[^\,]+?)(\,[^\,]+?)(\,[^\,]+?)\*[\d\w]{2}$
```

i.e.,

1. Replace the '.' with '[^\,]' to match any character except a comma rather than just any character at all; and
2. Replace '*' with '+' to avoid matches of length zero.

Comment: @sunghun : I've put in a new regexp to provide for the requirements mentioned. Let me know if it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid empty group, just replace `*` by `+`:

```
^\$[A-Z]{5,6}(,.+?)(,.+?)(,.+?)(,.+?)\*\w{2}$
```

Thre're no needs to escape the comma and `\w` includes `\d`, in fact it's equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`